How to quotient out by group action in SageMath
I have a Graph $G$ in Sage and a set $S$ of subsets of vertices of the graph. This set is closed under the action of the automorphism group $Aut(G)$, and I'd like to extract one representative of each orbit.
Is there an easy Sage way of doing this? (Like maybe using canonical_form with a partition?)

I think the following would work: Create a new graph $G'$ with vertices being the vertices of $G$ and one new vertex for each subset $s$ of vertices in $S$, add an edge from $s$ to each of its elements, and then call automorphism_group on $G'$ with partition $[V(G), S]$ and return the orbits.  This should return orbits in $G$ of the vertices and separately orbits of subsets in $S$ under the action of $Aut(G)$.
If anyone knows Sage well enough to tell me whether or not there's a better way, I'd appreciate it.

Okay, I think I have a second way of doing this in Sage. Call automorphism_group on G, and strong_generating_system on the result.  Convert the members of S into 0-1 boolean vectors of length $|V(G)|$, and for each member $s$ check enumeration_mod_permgroup.is_canonical(sgs,s).  If anyone knows Sage well, would that be significantly faster or significantly slower that the above?
